# How to add YAML front matter to an SVG image

Tags: yaml, jekyll, github-pages

I am hosting a web comic using Jekyll and Github Pages. I have so far written an HTML file which *should* iterate over the images, however I am not able to get data from the SVG. As mentioned before, I need to asdd some data to the file itself (title text, date published, etc). Is there a
way to add it to the XML file itself?

**EDIT:** I have tried to directly add the front matter to the SVG, and it did not display.
**EDIT #2:** My repository is [here](https://github.com/LinuxRocks2000/LinuxRocks2000.github.io)
**EDIT #3:** I am now using a more flexible custom build system. For anyone else with the same problem: Try Javascript/JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it seems Jekyll doesn't parse SVG images. I decided to use a JSON file instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have jekyll process your svg by adding a front matter before svg markup.

example : **star.svg**

```
---
layout: nil
title: My svg star
date_published: 2019-05-08
---
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M50,3l12,36h38l-30,22l11,36l-31-21l-31,21l11-36l-30-22h38z"
fill="#FF0" stroke="#FC0" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Note that you have to set `layout: nil`.

Comment: Did you have public repository url ?

Comment: Front matter must come first before any svg markup.

Comment: Ok, so before the xml tag?

Comment: i added it before the svg markup, and it works however i cannot retrieve the data i added

Comment: Your question was "how to add a front matter to an svg image ?". I've answered to this question. "How to use front matter variables contained in svg files ?" is another question that needs more clarifications : existing code, desired output, ... If my answer is ok for you, you can approve it and ask another question.